# Unable to get X display settings

Tags: linux, x11, putty, xming

I have downloaded and installed Xming on my Windows 7 laptop. I am using a PUTTY session to connect to my linux box and start a X Windows application but the $DISPLAY variable is itself not getting setup properly:

I see the XMING icon on my system tray

X0.hosts file:

```
localhost
10.24.0.144
```

**Putty->X11->Enable X11 Forwarding [X Display Location - :0.0]**

But:

```
@10.24.0.144's password:
Last login: Sun Sep 20 11:57:37 2015 from 10.21.200.197
# echo $DISPLAY

#
```

As such I am not able to successfully start the X Windows app from Putty?

Comment: Is the DISPLAY set and exported in the bash file?

Comment: But I am plugged into a local network - so what value of DISPLAY I should set: export DISPLAY=:0.0

Comment: @Barett's solution is good.  Also: have you configured your Linux box to allow X11 forwarding?  See `man sshd_config` for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the shell try : `export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:10.0"` . Test with `echo` and then try X window application.

To permanently set it up, update the `bashrc` file.

Comment: Thanks - but when we configure via PUTTY client doesn't it should setup the values - so setting it up in Putty client does not matter

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this box in PuTTY? The box below can help tweak your display location, if it needs to be customized.

[image: PuTTY x11 screen shot]